# Excel 2016, using Go To Special in a protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have built a large program which at some point uses "Go To Special" in its VBA code. This workbook has to be protected, and I can't find any way to enable using "Go To Special" in a protected sheet, so the code won't run. Anyone has an idea on how to enable it?

Comment: Unprotect Sheet in the code > Use `GoTo Special` > Re-Protect Sheet.

Comment: ah right, haven't thought about it! I will give it a try, thanks you!

Comment: success ,it worked, thanks you very much.

Comment: Have you considered using [Worksheet.Protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) with the `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` option? This will allow any VBA based operation to bypass worksheet protection.

Comment: This workbook should always be protected, so is there a way to protect the sheet this way (setting  UserinterfaceOnly = True) without calling a macro? (I have only one macro which creates the final product hence it is called only once the user finishes working on the workbook)